# Can't debug android app after adding .aar file

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, aar, honeywell

I need to develop support to interact with the build-in barcode scanner (my test device is Honeywell CK65).

Therefore I downloaded the mobility sdk for android from the manufacturer website and added the .aar file to my project. After that, I can't debug my project anymore. It says **"waiting for the debugger to attach"**. App starts normally without debugging. In both cases (debug and no debug) android studio displays **No debuggable process** in the **Android monitor** window.

The option `Tools->Android->Enable ADB integration` is enabled.

I also added

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
}
```

to `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

add .arr file into libs folder check libs folder is created correctly or not then try